# Add Member's birthdate from Backend and shows it on frontside

Tags: customization

I want to add functionality like Add member record with birthrate and as per the current date it shows on page.

**Ex :**

Add record - [name] [birth_date] [position]

And on the front page we can shows all the member list who have birthday today.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Ways are many I'm afraid. What have you tried? Perhaps you can check how to add [custom post type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) and [custom field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section) for a basic understanding.

Comment: I have tried Custom Post Types plugin but no result.. thanx.. you have any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

**Step - 1**

Create a custom post type called Birthday

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_birthday_content_type' );
function register_birthday_content_type() {
    register_post_type( 'birthday', array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Birthdays',
        'singular_name' => 'Birthday',
       ),
      'description' => 'Your description',
      'public' => true,
      'menu_position' => 20,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' )
    ));
}
```

**Step - 2**

Since you have a birthday date field, I prefer using ACF (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

Install ACF and add additional fields such as birth date and position

**Step - 3**

Write query to fetch the posts which has birth date = Today.

Here is the documetation: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

This is one of the quickest way.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do it but I will approach it by creating a custom post type first for the **Members**, you can create that by pasting this code in your theme's functions.php using the code below:

```
   function member_name() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Member Name', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Member Name', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Members', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Member Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Member', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Members', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Member ', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Member ', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Member ', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Member ', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Member ', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Member ', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Member list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Member list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter Member list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Member Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Member Description', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'member_name', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'member_name', 0 );
```

Please refer here for the full documentation of the post type: codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

After you have a custom post type, The easiest way to add fields (birthday, position,etc) associated with custom post type is using the ACF plugin www.advancedcustomfields.com/ or you can code it by understanding for the meta boxes works with a custom post type, please refer here: codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

Lastly, after setting your member list, associating it with the proper fields and populating your data, you can display it in your theme, for example in your default homepage, let's use index.php for example in your theme folder, you can insert this example code to use wp_query to display and sort the custom meta associated with a custom post type:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'member_name' ),
    'order'                  => 'ASC',
    'orderby'                => 'date',
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'birthdate',
            'type'      => 'DATE',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Please refer with Wp_query's documentation for indepth usage: codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query